# Starting Programs From PHP

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I have Windows 7 x64 with XAMPP installed. How can I start .bat files located on my webserver?

I tried with

1. exec();
2. system();
3. shell_exec();
4. popen();

And with commands like

```
dir c:
```

It works.

But if I try with

```
notepad text.txt
```

No applications start!

Yesterday I tried with allocating the Python directory in the environment variables and I tried to start my program like this:

```
%python%/python teamviewer_start.py
```

and it worked yesterday, but not today/

My idea was to make a little "control panel" to start some programs directly from the Net, like TeamViewer, ThinVnc or Ammyy Admin. How can I do something like this?

This is my Python script:

```
import subprocess

import os

import wmi

os.system("start /b C:\Progra~2\TeamVi~1\Version6\TeamVi~1.exe")
```

This, in local, starts...

Comment: From the net? do you mean you want to control from the web your local computer?

Comment: Yes, like start programs like Teamviewer, Thinvnc or Ammyy...

Comment: @DamienPirsy: ps: how can I subscribe my question to receive mail when something changes? :D

Comment: @DamienPirsy if you want to look my control panel (or its skeleton) go here: http://bonny1992.no-ip.org

Comment: If you mean getting notified when someone comments, it's almost always automatic (if it's your question/answer), otherwise you have to be targeted by the other using '@'+ your name

Comment: @DamienPirsy No mail arrived :( however... do you saw my "cp"? :)

Comment: @DamienPirsy I wanted to control it by my iPhone too :)

Comment: You cannot start programs via the browser. `exec()` executes a program on the server, as the same user as PHP is running.

Comment: @CodeCaster but until yesterday my > %python%/python pythonapp.py worked! :)

Comment: @CodeCaster and I set permissions to all users for this files :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
shell_exec("start notepad text.txt");
```

I tested in Win 7 64bits (using wamp) inside `cmd` and works:

```
php -r "shell_exec('start notepad txt.txt');"
```

**EDIT:**

If you uses [WScript.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky):

```
<?php
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->run("cmd /K notepad",9,false);
```

It start, but with SYSTEM user (see in task manager), and not visible =/. Maybe someone can help with this user change? Or you can try start an .BAT.

Comment: Nothing starts :( If I try to execute the command "start notepad ..." from cmd it starts... :(

Comment: never used wscript! xD how can i use this? :)

Comment: all i know is on the link above, it's a COM =/, the behavior is similar to shell_exec and others, with a few options...